# Video player to play all files?

Tags: video, media-player

As VLC is not available for android, which Android player supports most video formats (and faster and lighter if possible)?
For example currently i use kascend media player, it can also play flv files (without flash player) and faster then other flv players.

Comment: I think this would be better if you were asking for support for a particular format that wasn't playable in kascend, or something.

Comment: Kascend does not play some flv files that are playable in some other players. It would be great to have an all in one media player

Comment: I have a 500 MHz phone with low memory. Only kascend has played a higher resolution flv file faster than others, but not perfectly.

Comment: [VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) is currently in beta testing: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html

Comment: VLC Beta is also on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon

Answer (score 3):

I use [QQPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tencent.research.drop&feature=search_result)

> Mobile QQ player ... supports all the popular formats of videos
>   on the market, including AVI, FLV, MP4, 3GP, MKV, MOV and etc. In
>   addition, QQ Player also supports SRT, SMI plug-in subtitle and MKV
>   embedded subtitle, as well as multiple audio tracks switching.

Answer (score 3):

I like [MoboPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil&hl=en)

It seems the fastest on my Xoom, and plays back nearly anything I throw at it flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

[VLC for Android](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html) is now [available as beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon).

Answer (score 2):

Arcmedia is also a nice player. It is based on ffmpeg, so it'll play pretty much anything you throw at it.

Answer (score 2):

[MXPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en)
It supports most of the formats

Answer (score 1):

VLC is available for Android already!
Here are some [best android players](http://video-player-software.blogspot.com/2012/09/best-android-player-for-android-phone.html) for you!

Answer (score 0):

If someone gave me the choice of picking just one media player to take to a deserted island, I would most definitely plonk for VideoLan’s VLC Media Player. VLC, the free media player popular for its capability to play most media formats(MPEG-1, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DivX, mp3, ogg...) While, no-one seems to know much how to import and play Blu-ray discs using VLC (even you’ve gotten rid of the copy protection and can actually make a backup!).

no worry! An approach is presented at [this website](http://portable-device-conversion.com/ripping-encrypted-blu-ray-discs-onto-vlc-media-player-for-uploading/).

If VLC doesn't play your blu-ray movie, we can upgrade the VLC to the latest version, install it and replay it, but it seems to be a bit complex for us. And sometimes, our Blu-ray was burned at 8X or 16X speed while the computer can only handle 2X or 4X Media. On this occasion, we'd better convert the blu-rays to videos for smoothly playback with a Blu-ray Ripper, which enables us rip and convert Blu-ray to a common video for VLC for playback effortlessly.

Comment: Seems like your talking about using VLC Player for PC, not for Android.

Answer (score 0):

The best player is **DICE player**... you can play any format on it without your phone breaking a sweat.. My 3 years old Galaxy S is able to play 720p videos perfectly and also 1080p(though choppily). All the other players on the market failed to do that for me. The only other player that does all that was the default Galaxy S player but as I installed CyanogenMod I lost it.