# Is it possible to play real media on an android tablet?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, video

I would like to play the real media videos at http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/index.php/Main/AdditiveCombinatoricsMinicourse . However neither vlc nor mxplayer seem to work. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried real player? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.real.RealPlayer.na  Alternatively have a read here: lots of media player recommendations: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/video-player-to-play-all-files?rq=1

Comment: @RossC  It isn't even listed as an option when I click on the .rm link.

Comment: That's really pants... Sorry I just assumed it would work. Any of the other ones viable?